# Probability with Bivariate Normal

Tags: probability

[image]

I am almost done with my homework assignment but I have one question...In the starred problem where do the underlined numbers come from? My problem is very similar to this one and I was trying to use it as an example but I don't get where these numbers come from.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: What kind of random variable is $5X-Y$? There is a very important result that you need to learn, and always remember, about this point.  Next, what is the mean and the variance of $5X-Y$? There is another important result that you need to learn, and to remember, about this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are normal, so is $5X-Y$ (this is an important result, as noted by Dilip Sarwate in the comment). You should have a result that says that the variance of $aX+bY$ is $$a^2 \mathop{Var}(X) + b^2 \mathop{Var}(Y) + 2 a b \mathop{Cov}(X,Y).$$

Comment: That helps a lot thank you!